# ERROR MESSAGE when cassandra python Driver accept parameters from user GUI

Tags: cassandra-2.0

i'm using cassandra 2.1 and CQL 3.2.1 , i want to let user specify keyspace name ,replication strategy , replication factor from UI , and then pass these values to query to execute Insert CQL , but give me an syntax error , i try a lot but nothing go write >>
i'm create keyspace -> connect
and column family -> keyspaces
but insertion cause error
here is my code :

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

class Connection():

    def __init__ (self , ips , keyspace ,replication_strategy ,replication_factor):

        self.keyspace=keyspace
        self.ips =ips
        self.replication_strategy=replication_strategy
        self.replication_factor=replication_factor
        cluster = Cluster([ips])
        session = cluster.connect() 
        session.execute("CREATE keyspace IF NOT EXISTS connect with replication={ 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' :1}")
        session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS connect.keyspaces (id int primary key , keyspaces_name text, replication_strategy text, replication_factor int)")
        session.execute("INSERT INTO connect.keyspaces(id , keyspaces_name , replication_strategy ,replication_factor ) VALUES (1 " +','  + self.keyspace + ',' + self.replication_strategy +',' + self.replication_factor + ")")

and the ERROR MESSAGE IS :
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3822, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:74332)
    raise self._final_exception
SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:125 no viable alternative at input ',' (...) VALUES (1 ,noon,[SimpleStrategy],...)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there is a syntax error in the INSERT statement you're building. It might be easier to troubleshoot if you print the string query you've built.

Alternatively I would suggest parameterizing your query to let the driver do formatting:
http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries